# Designated initializer different behavior before and after c++20

Tags: c++

I came across this strange behavior and I can't find a good explanation of it.

The code below will compile successfully *before c++20* and only fail if `explicit` is used.

```cpp
struct Square {
  int area = 10;

  Square() = default; // only if this is explicit will the compile fail
  Square(const Square& other) = delete;
  Square(Square&& other) = delete;
  Square& operator =(Square&& square) = delete;
  Square& operator =(const Square& square) = delete;
};

int main() {
  Square s = {
      .area = 10
  };
}
```

Which is strange on its own but turning the compiler to c++20 will make the above code fail with these error messages

gcc

> could not convert brace-enclosed initializer list

clang

> no matching constructor for initialization of 'Square'

---

**Question**:

- Why does it compile successfully before c++20 unless `explicit`? In other words what implicit conversion takes place to make that happen?
- What changed in c++20 that made this code fail to compile?

Comment: The answer is both of  [eerorika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033689/8033550) and [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033689/8033550) 's explanations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does it compile successfully before c++20 ...

The program is ill-formed prior to C++20.

Designited initialisers did not exist in the language prior to C++20. It compiles because of a language extension.

> What changed in c++20 that made it not compile anymore?

The program is still ill-formed in C++20.

Designated initialisers are introduced to the language in C++20, and it appears that the rules are slightly different from what the language extension does. The related rules are (from latest draft):

> [dcl.init.list] List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If the braced-init-list contains a designated-initializer-list, T shall be an aggregate class. ...
> - ...
>
> [dcl.init.aggr] An aggregate is an array or a class ([class]) with
>
> - no user-declared or inherited constructors ([class.ctor]),
> - ...

The behavioural difference of the language extension prior to C++20 may be related to the change in definition of what is an aggregate, as explained by [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033689/2079303)

Answer (score 3):

In C++20, your class is no longer an aggregate.  Since it is not an aggregate, you cannot use a designated initializer.  This change is the result of [P1008](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf) which removed the presence of user provided defaulted or deleted constructors as qualifying for being an aggregate.  The example given for why this change needed to be made was:

```
struct X {
  int i{4};
  X() = default;
};

int main() {
  X x1(3); // ill-formed - no matching c’tor
  X x2{3}; // compiles!
}
```

where `X x2{3}` should not compile but it does because `X() = default;` doesn't stop it from being an aggregate.